# Python - How do I return a variable defined from an imported python function?

Tags: python, function, variables, import, global-variables

I've recreated this error in a simpler file.

**main.py**

```
from funcA import *

test()
print(x)
```

**funcA.py**

```
def test():
    global x
    y = 2
    return x
```

I receive "NameError: name 'x' is not defined", what am I missing?

Comment: You haven't defined `x` anywhere... I guess you.meany `x = 2`? In any case, that would not create `x` in main.py

Answer (score 1):

`from funcA import *` creates a *new* variable named `x` in the global scope of `main.py`. Its initial value comes from `funcA.x`, but it is a distinct variable that isn't linked to `funcA.x`.

When you call `test`, you update the value of `funcA.x`, but `main.x` remains unchanged.

After you call `test`, you can see the change by looking at `funcA.x` directly.

```
from funcA import *
import funcA


test()
print(funcA.x)
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated and well explained! That fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a global variable outside the function.
The `global` keyword cannot be used like that.
There's must be `x` outside the function.

```
# funcA.py
x = "something"

def test():
    global x
    y = 2
    return x
```